# Bulk publishing Issue in Fatwire

Tags: publishing, bulk, fatwire

Currently performing a Bulk publish using Mirror Queue for around 11000 assets.
Have tried the same in lower environments and was successful.

No error logged @ source and destination futuretense logs. The asset update got logged at destination for long time and no updates later. Publishing process still keeps rolling in source.

No stuck threads and memory consumption looks good on both environments.

Any inputs for the same, will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What is the Fatwire version? Please note that mirror to server publishing is no longer supported in Oracle Webcenter Sites 11.1.1.8. Real time publishing is more robust and less error prone.